# How to take input from user while using CountDownTimer in android

Tags: android, input, countdowntimer

Here at CountDownTimer below, I want to have a user input value in milli seconds instead of pre loaded value of 30000.
Please anybody help in this case. I am not able to figure out myself.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView mTextField;
    EditText mEditText;
    Button mButton;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTextField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerView);
        mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);


        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Turning of the button until the timer finishes
                mButton.setEnabled(false);
                mButton.setClickable(false);

                new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) { // Here I want to have a user input value in milli seconds instead of pre loaded value of 30000

                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                    }

                    public void onFinish() {
                        mTextField.setText("done!");
                        // Turning on the button when the timer has finnished
                        mButton.setEnabled(true);
                        mButton.setClickable(true);
                    }
                }.start();


            }
        });

    }

}**strong text**
```

Answer (score 2):

It is very simple, give any option for user input like an edit text and then pass those values as parameters in the CountDownTimer.

```
// 3000 and 200 will be input from user
long millisinFuture= 3000;
long delayTime=200;

new CountDownTimer(millisinFuture, delayTime) { // Here I want to have a user input value in milli seconds instead of pre loaded value of 30000

                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                }

                public void onFinish() {
                    mTextField.setText("done!");
                    // Turning on the button when the timer has finnished
                    mButton.setEnabled(true);
                    mButton.setClickable(true);
                }
            }.start();
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.
I want to take integer input but how I can convert it into milliseconds so that I can pass it to the CountDowntimer.

Comment: you will have to decide for that whether you want input in hours , seconds or minutes, if seconds then you can convert using following standard 1 second=1000 milliseconds and you should be well know how to use long and int

Comment: Actually I am having problem in parsing the Edit Text field.
Not able to find proper syntax for parsing the edit text value which I am taking as integer to milli seconds

Comment: you can edit your question and add there the issue you are facing or post it separately or elaborate it